# Enable link to be opened in popup window in Bot

Tags: javascript, c#, botframework

Is there option in the bot framework that makes a link to open in a popup window?

Please let me know.
I know how to provide link in chat window. but dont know how to make that link to be opened in pop up window.

code to include link.
`[Hello, world!](http://example.com/){target="_blank"}`

Comment: Code to include link ---->      [link](url){:target="_blank"}

Comment: You're asking for channel client functionality and not bot functionality. If you want to know how to implement channel-specific behavior then you need to explain what channel you're using.

Comment: Hi Kyle, I am asking about bot functionality only. In my case bot is returning a link for an query. I want that link to be opened as pop up not in new window or new tab.

Comment: What channel are you using?

Comment: I am using Web Chat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found solution.

Below are the steps.

1. In Bot solution added link using HeroCard.

   ```
               var card = new HeroCard
               {
                   Text = "Click below link to open form",
                   Buttons = new List<CardAction>
               {
                   new CardAction(ActionTypes.PlayAudio, title: "Request form", value: linkulr),
               },
               };
   ```
2. In Bot client, edit botchat.js file

`if(e instanceof o.OpenUrlAction) {
                        if(e.title="Request Form")   //Checking the title
                        {
                            OpenPopup(e.url, 'Request Form', 750, 555); //Calling function to open the url in pop up.
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        window.open(e.url);
                        }
                    }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use, adapative cards, to open or any action to happen in botframework
https://adaptivecards.io/designer

Sample code for it

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "Media"
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
            "title": "Hello world",
            "url":"http:helloworl.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vinod. But i want to open link like model window. Javascript: window.open(url). How to achive this in bot.

Comment: yes, this will open up, in new window only, adapative cards are the only way do that right now, if we code the html in the reply, it will show as it is, see the samples present in adapative cards for web check in, it will open up in tabs only.